# Gauss`s theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Use Gauss`s theorem to show that $2^{\frac{1}{n}}$,$3^{\frac{1}{n}}$ are not rational numbers for all $n\in \mathbb{N}.$

I do not know what is "Gauss`s theorem" that the writer want us to use, could anyone help me?

Comment: They are certainly rational when $n=1$

Comment: I think there taking about Gauss's Lemma https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(polynomial)

Comment: Apparently the rational root theorem is a special case, so perhaps you can use it as follows: The only rational solutions to $x^{n}-2=0$ can be $\pm 2, \pm 1$ but clearly this does not work for $n$ an integer greater than $1$. Thus $2^{1/n}$ is irrational for all integers greater than $1$.

Comment: @i8Σπ_821  I do not think that this link is related ..... I am in mathematical analysis not physics.

Comment: Ah alright. Disregarded then. Apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $n >1$, if either $x^n -2$ or $x^n-3$ has a rational root, then it must be an integer (from the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem#Proof_using_Gauss.27s_lemma) which follows from [Gauss's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(polynomial))). But if $a$ is an integer such that $a^n =2$, then $2|a$ and then $a > 2 \Rightarrow a^n > 2$ which is a contradiction. Similarly if $b^n =3$, $3|b$ and then $b>3 \Rightarrow b^n > 3$, a contradiction.

Thus $x^n-2$ and $x^n-3$ have no integral roots and hence no rational roots. So $2^{1/n}$ and $3^{1/n}$ are not rational for $n$ > 1.